# How to derived an equivalent real-valued system model of the complex value MIMO system?

Tags: complex-numbers, nonlinear-system, signal-processing

I have been reading this paper

["Fifty Years of MIMO Detection: The Road to Large-Scale MIMOs"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7244171)
and see an equivalent real-values system model of the complex value MIMO system without any proof or at least any intuition

The complex value system model

$y = Hs + n$

The real equivalent system model 
\begin{array}{l}
\widetilde y = \widetilde H\widetilde s + \widetilde n\\
\widetilde y = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{Real}}\left( y \right)}\\
{{\rm{Imag}}\left( y \right)}
\end{array}} \right],\widetilde s = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{Real}}\left( s \right)}\\
{{\rm{Imag}}\left( s \right)}
\end{array}} \right],\widetilde n = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{Real}}\left( n \right)}\\
{{\rm{Imag}}\left( n \right)}
\end{array}} \right]\\
\tilde H = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{Real}}\left( H \right)}&{{\rm{ - Imag}}\left( H \right)}\\
{{\rm{Imag}}\left( H \right)}&{{\rm{Real}}\left( H \right)}
\end{array}} \right]
\end{array}

I really interested in the detail of this presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to decompose into the real and imaginary components, i.e.,
\begin{align}
y := y_{\rm R} + i y_{\rm I},
\end{align}
where $y_{\rm R}  := \operatorname{Real}\{y\} $ and $y_{\rm I}  := \operatorname{Imag}\{y\} $.

Similarly, $H := H_{\rm R} + i H_{\rm I}$, $s = s_{\rm R} + i s_{\rm I}$, and $n = n_{\rm R} + i n_{\rm I}$.

Now, take your linear complex-valued system model and replace with the appropriated decomposed signal components, i.e.,
\begin{align}
y &= Hs + n\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\\
y_{\rm R} + i y_{\rm I}  
&= \left( y_{\rm R} + i y_{\rm I}  \right) \left( s_{\rm R} + i s_{\rm I} \right) + \left( n_{\rm R} + i n_{\rm I} \right) \\
&= \left( H_{\rm R} s_{\rm R} -  H_{\rm I} s_{\rm I}  \right) + i \left( H_{\rm I} s_{\rm R} +  H_{\rm R} s_{\rm I} \right) \\
&= \left[1 \quad i \right] \begin{bmatrix} H_{\rm R} & -H_{\rm I} \\ H_{\rm I} & H_{\rm R} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} s_{\rm R} \\ s_{\rm I} \end{bmatrix} + \left[1 \quad i \right] \begin{bmatrix} n_{\rm R} \\ n_{\rm I} \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

In the real-valued system model, just treat the real and imaginary components as different coordinates per se. I hope it helps now.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understand your idea. But should it be that
${y_{{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} al}} + i{y_{{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} ag}} = \left( {{H_{{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} al}} + i{H_{Imag}}} \right)\left( {{s_{{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} al}} + i{s_{Imag}}} \right) + \left( {{n_{{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} al}} + i{n_{{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} ag}}} \right)$